# Select the data from input

Tags: reactjs

My app uses a select with different values, which work also as a search. Now if i click on save after i inserted 2 names i get an an array with 2 objects. After that if i will insert just 1 name and click save, the previous array is changed with a new one which is composed only from 1 element, in fact i deleted the first array, but i don't want to lose the previous array. I want to keep the previous array, and if i will add a value that not exists in it, i want to add the new value, and i fact i will have an array with 3 objects. How to solve this issue?

link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ritchie-oxhuk

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do, is to save after every Save buton click(i.e. to concat arrays) and save only the unique items.

if you are familer with ES6, you can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object of javascript. Its an handfull tool to choose unique items from an array.

```
Array.from(new Set(savedItems.concat(selectedItems)).values())
```

you can first concat the two array, then set them to a Set to remove the duplicates and then convert them back to the original Array.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-pascal-5fo3n

Comment: it works, but how to do this?  `const saveBtn = () => {
    saveItems(Array.from(new Set(savedItems.concat(selectedItems)).values()));
    setState([]);
    console.log(savedItems) }` , because i need `savedItems` in `saveBtn`, now the constant is undefined on firts click, it appear only on second click. I know that this is happening because useState is async. How to solve this?

Comment: Please go through the codesandbox link.. i have given. It will work, but you have to maintain 2 arrays. and you dont need the search function either..

Comment: @Asking which constant variable are you talking about?